# ASUS computer win11: enable start machine on lid open

Tags: sleep, hibernate, windows-11, wake-up, lid

In many of today's PCs, the computer will automatically start from a shutdown state when the lid is opened. This is just like a chromebook or Lenovo's Flip to Start feature. My ASUS computer had this feature, but after upgrading to win11, it disappeared. Not sure if it has something to do with win11. In the BIOS, I have it enabled. In the power settings, I have lid open action = turn on display. There is a MyASUS app that comes preinstalled, but I'm not sure if some setting there can change this, or some windows settings. It may also have something to do with sleep/hibernate?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it set on lid-close to sleep or to shutdown? You can see that in *Power Options > Choose what closing the lid does*, action "When I close the lid".

Comment: It's set to sleep. But does that matter? The issue is that opening lid does not wake up the computer from a shut down state, not really about closing the lid.

Comment: I would like this too, but I fear that is just an option for waking out of sleep.